# Combine two views on one page

Tags: 7, views

I have 2 custom views(block types) 'view_A' and 'view_B', one shows content the other shows orders. I need to cobmine them in a single page displaying in 2 different tables. Really dosen't make sense to bundle events and orders in one table.

I tried creating a page, but I can't select 'block' for the context type. I can only select nodes. What's the best way using the UI in Drupal 7 to do this?

Answer (score 8):

A simpler way can be:

**Current Setup:**

1. View A (show content)
2. View B (show orders)

**Steps:**

1. Create a new "page display" of the View A and set the path and menu if you have to.

2 a. Then on the view header or footer (*depending if you want the View B before or after View A*) add a global view area that will show the View B when viewing View A page.

[image: Global View Area]

2 b. Select from your existing views the View B

[image: Select View B]

2 c. Apply the change to the current display and you are done.

Comment: When I check off "Global view area" and hit Apply, I get "Changes cannot be made to a locked view."  What is this and how can I get around it?

Comment: That message indicate that the view is lock by other user or session in the edit mode. This usually have a message in top saying to "break" the lock.

Answer (score 3):

You could just make a blank page with a custom path (i.e. /my-empty-page) and no content.

Then in the structure>blocks menu assign the blocks to the content region and set them to only show up on the URL for the page you just made?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Views Field View](http://drupal.org/project/views_field_view) as well. So you create 2 separate views and then decide which one do you want to place in which region i.e header or footer and based on that add the  Global: View (Views field view) from the global section.

The only difference which I know from the above method is this module allows you to pass arguments as well from the parent view and has token integration as well.

Comment: Could we apply this method with this question?
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/79096/need-you-advice-how-to-build-this-website-has-the-same-views