# need you advice how to build this website has the same views

Tags: views, multi-sites, routes

[image: the core function that I am going to development]
`The search info module is the common feature for all the airport1,2,3`

with this requirement do I need to set up multisite for ariport1,2 ,3?

Could any give some tips what should I use (drupal) to develop this kind of website.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the info that you've given,
I'll suggest you to use quicktabs module for tabs and views exposed filter for search.
If you're asking what CMS to use I guess that is inappropriate to ask here.

Comment: How about we implement airport1,2,and ariport3