# Merging Two Views

Tags: views

I have two views. One that shows a list of Invoices Receivable. I'm using Views Aggregate Plus module to sun up all of these. I have another view that shows all the Invoices Payable and also uses View Aggregate Plus to sum up all of these invoices. This works fine.

What I would like to do is take the Total column from the Invoices Receivable and then minus the total of Invoices Payable from it and place it on either view or pass it to a third view if possible.

Is there a way to merge these two views and all the fields into a third or will I have to write some of my own PHP code?

Comment: possibly try with custom code refer this link https://www.drupal.org/node/748844 and http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/42506/combine-two-views-on-one-page

Comment: This really doesn't make sense to me. I'm fairly new to Drupal and was wondering if there might be a module or is there a way to change the value from positive to negative to do a calculation