# How merge two different views on single page?

Tags: views

How can I merge two different **views** on single page by displaying value with common filter condition for both views.

Ex: I have view1 and View2 and now I want to display both views on single page and filter condition if I select Id card number from View1 along with view1 fields the respected linked users in view2 should display.

Comment: can you please explain it more what you wanna do??

Comment: @Adi: i have edited take a look, if u know any idea on this please share with me, i will be  thankful to u.

Comment: what want to do .this can be done using on view then why you create 2 views

Comment: @Adi: need this because i have content type where in id card no is node with different other fields , along with this i have other content type with multiple fields i want to create view for all this n show on same page with common filtercondition  so i need to merge on single page

Comment: this can be done using relation or add expose filter value

Comment: you can link another node using node reference then use in vew

Comment: @Adi:please can you please elaborate stepwise what exactly need to do?to merge these two views and add filter for both

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30812/discussion-between-adi-and-kashish).

Answer (score 2):

[Views Global Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/global_filter)

> Use Views Global Filter on sites that feature multiple Views. You want
>   the views to be driven by the same filter selection, for instance a
>   country, a date range, a search term or even proximity to a post code.
>   These views may be on the same page or scattered across several pages
>   on your site, however you want to offer the visitor the convenience of
>   setting the filter for all these views only once, for instance when
>   they first land on your site. Views Global Filter implements the
>   picked once, operates site-wide (POOS) principle. This means you can
>   place anywhere on your site a selection widget (drop-down, check boxes
>   etc) to globally filter all or some of your views. When the user picks
>   a value from the global selector, the value is invisibly passed as a
>   contextual filter to whatever views you like, even when these reside
>   across multiple pages. This avoids you having to duplicate filters and
>   avoids the visitor having to re-select their choice as they go from
>   page to page.

[Combine two views on one page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/42506/combine-two-views-on-one-page)

Comment: Alongside with the module indicated (Global Filter), you can give a try to [Views Filter Harmonizer](https://www.drupal.org/project/filter_harmonizer), a very powerfull module.