# Common filter condition in views

Tags: views

I have master content type

1. content type Room,
2. content type Projects,
3. content type vaccine.

This is how these related

a. Room **ID[node]** of room content type is entity reference **field[field_roomidd]** in Projects content type, also in **vaccine[field_vroomid]**.

b. and vaccine **id [node of vaccine content type]** is entity reference field in content type projects.

Now I want to create view of content type Room and projects and  have merged the two views of content type Room and Content type projects.

My requirement is whenever we select room id in filter condition it should show the for that particular room id what's the vaccine created, and projects are exist....I am stuck here please anyone help me on this.

Comment: why you ask same question with different condition

Comment: it is same as http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/178990/merging-two-different-views-on-single-page with different condition

Comment: @Adi: am confused with relationship of this content types how to connect in view....also i tried with global filter condition its not working with me:(

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/SkYja.png check link hopefully its helps you

Comment: @Adi: in view there is no link to view option is not there.....what is the use of it?

Comment: did you used penals ??

Comment: @Adi: i am not using panels....after merging two views i added global filter including two fields but its unable to filter the for both merged views...as well i am not getting why filter condition added is coming in between both the views

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30859/discussion-between-adi-and-kashish).

Comment: @Adi:you there?